# Sound in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

Why sound cannot be played in android version 4.1? When in browser sound can be played very well.

i am trying to play the sound when the card match and when the card mismatch.

I have currently developed my game using HTML5, CSS and javascript.

Javascript:

```
function playAudio(sAudio) {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('audioEngine');
        if(audioElement !== null) {
            audioElement.src = sAudio;
                audioElement.play();
    }
}
function playAudio(sAudio) {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('audioEngine');
        if(audioElement !== null) {
            audioElement.src = sAudio;
                audioElement.play();
    }
}
    function checkPattern() {
        if (isMatchPattern()) {
            $(".card-flipped").removeClass("card-flipped").addClass("card-removed");
                if(document.webkitTransitionEnd){
                    $(".card-removed").bind("webkitTransitionEnd",  removeTookCards);
                }else{
                    playAudio("mp3/WinLevel.mp3");
                    removeTookCards();
                }
            } else {
            $(".card-flipped").removeClass("card-flipped");
            playAudio("mp3/WrongLose.mp3");
        }
    }

HTML5:

 <audio id="audioEngine">
    our browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you trying in  a application or in the android browser

Comment: I am trying to run the application in android mobile phone version 4.1. I have wrap my application using PhoneGap. Everything works fine, just that am having problem with the sound. Is there any possible solution?

Comment: check this one, some times help you http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/